Effectively simple set
I need help with the book by soare recursively enumerables degree: On The Page 79 Why  $$W_e\subseteq \bar{S}\Longrightarrow W_e \subseteq\{0,1,...,2e\}$$?


It looks like the contrapositive of what you are after falls out of the construction of $S$ (Post's simple Set). If there is $x\in W_e$ such that $x>2e$, then $(e,x)\in A$. But if $(e,x)\in A$, then $x\in S$, so $W_e\not\subseteq\overline{S}$.

Perhaps, I do not quite understand how do we make use of $x\in S$ ? i.e. why is this important to know ?

I think that we just need $$W_e \nsubseteq {0,1,...,2e}$$

@user122424, my approach was to prove the contrapositive form of the statement you were asking about, so $W_e\not\subseteq{0,1,\dots,2e}$ would be only the starting assumption from which we wish to establish that $W_e\not\subseteq\overline{S}$. Showing that $W_e\cap S$ is not empty suffices to establish this.
